# date_bin or date_bucket postgre SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, bins

I'm looking to create 30 minute bins from a timestamp field in postgres SQL.

As an example, I have a bus trip which started at `2023-01-01 11.13 UTC` time in the `trip_time` field and there are 1,000 trips for the day all at different times (as an example).

I want to put the above example in a bin time that starts at 11.00 and any bus trip that starts at or after 11.30 goes into the next bin 30 minute bin etc. So above `date_bin()` field example would show `2023-01-01 11.00`, any trips at `2023-01-01 11.43` would be in the `2023-01-01 11.30` bin etc.

I also want to convert the result to a different timezone, as my system stores time in UTC but the trip is in Australia/Darwin time.

Documentation for `date_bin()` and `date_bucket` functions look like I have to put in an actual typed date, rather than using my table field as the source or origin field.

Is what I am proposing possible...?

I've tried the following and numerous different variations of below: -

```sql
SELECT date_bucket('minute'
                   ,30
                   ,trip_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Darwin')
FROM table;
```

```sql
SELECT date_bin('30 minute'
                ,trip_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Darwin'
                ,TIMEZONE '1970-01-01' )

FROM table;
```

I keep getting "No function matches.." errors.

Comment: I don't think there is a function called `date_bucket`. Also, in your `date_bin` function you have mentioned '30 minute' and not '30 minutes', not sure if that makes a difference but do give it a try.

Comment: `date_bucket` doesn't exist in PostgreSQL, that's a Microsoft SQL Server dialect. Your second call was close to correct: the signature is [`date_bin ( interval, timestamp, timestamp ) → timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE). You already gave it an interval and a timestamp so the third argument should be a timestamp, and '1970-01-01' is a s good an origin as any: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vJHbfrte)

Comment: @Zegared is not à SQL Server dialect but an ISO SQL standard feature.... Not actually implemented into PostGreSQL

Comment: A sincere thank you and apologies to kiner_shah, Zegarek and SQLpro. It looks like from these comments I am working with version 13.10 at my new place of employment so the date_bin function won't work. I'm also relatively new to SQL so I'm still finding my feet. Unsure how to give a 'Like' or 'Thank You' on your profile, but really appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN) function `date_bin` expects an interval, a timestamp or timestamptz and another timestamp or timestamptz but not what you called 'timezone' in the third argument. You can use simply `epoch` for 1970-01-01T00:00 UTC. `AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Darwin'` is to be placed after the function in order to affect the function result. Here is it fixed.

```sql
SELECT date_bin('30 minute', trip_time, 'epoch') AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Darwin'
from the_table;
```

Please note that `date_bin` does not exist before PG14. [Here](https://github.com/stefanov-sm/Pre-PG14-date_bin-function) is an implementation for earlier versions of Postgres.

Comment: A sincere thank you and apologies Stefanov. It looks like from the comments above, I am working with version 13.10 at my new place of employment so the date_bin function won't work. I'm also relatively new to SQL so I'm still finding my feet. Unsure how to give a 'Like' or 'Thank You' on your profile, but really appreciate your help.

Comment: I appreciate. You may accept the answer.